# calling a method in a template column in asp.net gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datagridtemplatecolumn

I have a GridView with a template column. In it I have a hyperlink control and I set it's visibility and Navigate URL dinamically using Eval. It all works fine but now I have to add a tooltip to the control, and I need to trim the space and comma at the end of the text.

I'm doing this:

```
ToolTip='<%# Eval("CombinedAccessions").ToString().TrimEnd(',', ' ') %>'
```

This works if coded on code behind, but fails when coded on the aspx page. But If I use just TrimEnd(), that function call works fine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @AmiramKorach I get "The server tag is not well formed."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `'` sign is breaking you attribute value of `ToolTip`. You can change the opening and closing sign to `"` but then it will be broken by the other `"` you have inside. The solution is to call a method in code behind:

```
protected string FormatCombinedAccessions(string value)
{
   return value.TrimEnd(',', ' ');
}
```

And in aspx:

```
ToolTip='<%# FormatCombinedAccessions((Convert.ToString(Eval("CombinedAccessions"))) %>'
```

I changed the `ToString` use to avoid null value.

Comment: you could also add the processing to the codebehind method:  `protected string Fn(object v) { return v.ToString.TrimEnd(',', ' '); }` and then it's cleaner in the front `<%# Fn(Eval("CombinedAccessions")) %>`